# What is the right way to pass an object created by std::bind to a function?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, functor, auto, stdbind

Let's assume I want to pass a function object created by `std::bind` by reference to a funktion:

```
void myCallback(int i, int j)
{
    std::cout << "toCall , i=" << i << " j=" << j;
}

void worker(std::function<void(int)> & callback)
{
    callback(111);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto foo = std::bind(myCallback, std::placeholders::_1, 222);
    worker(foo);
}
```

This does not compile

[image: compiler error]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2664    'void worker(std::function &)': cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'std::_Binder &,int>' to 'std::function
>   &'    asn1test_1  D:.....\asn1test_1.....cpp    302

However, passing by value works:

```
void worker(std::function<void(int)> callback)
{
    callback(111);
}
```

When I avoid "`auto`" and use instead

```
std::function<void(int)> foo = std::bind(myCallback, std::placeholders::_1, 222);
```

it works both with passing by reference or by value.

Q1: Why this behavior?

Q2: What would be the "right" way or datatype to pass an object created by `std::bind` to a function?

Answer (score 5):

`std::bind` does not return a `std::function`, at least, it is not required to do so.  When you do

```
auto foo = std::bind(myCallback, std::placeholders::_1, 222);
worker(foo);
```

`foo` is not a `std::function` and `worker` needs a non-const reference to a `std::function`, so the compiler errors out.  If you switch `worker` to being

```
void worker(const std::function<void(int)> & callback)
```

then you'll have a const reference and that can be bound to the temporary object that the conversion of `foo` to a `std::function` would produce.

---

I'd also like to point out that since we have lambdas, especially generic ones, `std::bind` really isn't needed.  Keeping the change to worker, you could instead make `foo`

```
auto foo = [](auto var){ return myCallback(var, 222); };
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::bind()` does not return a `std::function`, but an implementation-defined type that is *convertible* to a `std::function`.

When `worker()` takes its `callback` parameter as a non-const reference, that prevents the compiler from performing any *implicit* conversions, as a non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary object.  The reference will require an actual `std::function` object to have been created explicitly beforehand, eg:

```
std::function<void(int)> foo = std::bind(myCallback, std::placeholders::_1, 222);
worker(foo);
```

Changing `worker()` to take its `callback` parameter by value, or by const reference, allows the compiler to perform an implicit conversion for you, so you can pass the result of `std::bind()` as-is and the compiler will create a temp `std::function` for you.

Comment: Why the compiler cannot make a conversion when there is a non-const-reference?

Comment: Even if it *did* return a std::function, you could not then pass a reference to that (unnamed, temporary) value as a non-const lvalue reference.  The fact that a conversion is also involved doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @michael because a non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary object.  A const reference can

Comment: @ChrisDodd If `bind` did return a `std::function` then the code would work.  The OP is passing `foo` which would be an lvalue `std::function`.

Comment: I was (mis)reading the code to directly pass the `std::bind` as an argument to `worker`, with no `auto foo` involved.  Was the question edited?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the overhead of converting to a std::function, you could use a template:

```
template<class CB> void worker(CB callback) {
    callback(111);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```cpp
void worker(std::function<void(int)> const& callback) {
    callback(111);
}
```

because then implicit conversion from `foo` to temporary `std::function` object can be made.

Comment: really the issue is that you can't pass a reference to an unnamed temp as a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: I was (mis)reading the code to directly pass the `std::bind` as an argument to `worker`.

Comment: I got that, that's why I deleted my comment to your first comment. @ChrisDodd if you downvoted because of this reason, could you remove the downvote now